# Non-public android classes

Tags: android

Hi to all android devlopers.
Please, help me out from this:

1)How do i use non public classes in android like `telephony`, `android.telephony.CallManager` in my android application?

2) How do I import this telephony packages in my activity class and make it allow to access its functionality?

Comment: I'm just curious. Why do u need it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't and you shouldn't. These internal classes/APIs can change at any time without warning during an Android upgrade. there's no guarantee that they're implemented in the exact same way across different vendors.

Such changes can cause your application to break.

You should only use the public classes included in the android.jar

Answer (score 1):

Reflection?

```
ClassLoader classLoader = TestActivity.class.getClassLoader();
final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
try {
    final Class<?> classCallManager =
        classLoader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager");
} catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("TestActivity", e);
}
```

And add

```
READ_PHONE_STATE
```

to your Manifest.xml

Comment: thanks for replaying..I have used this piece of code,but still it's not working for me.It's raising an exception "class not found"...